# The node triggered garbage collection event through not reached the max size limit

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection

I am using this command to startup the node.js (`v16.20.2`) application:

```
node --max-old-space-size=256 --max-semi-space-size=128 --trace-gc ./bin/server-express.js >> ws.log 2>&1 &
```

After the application is started, I check the memory usage statistics:

```
{ 
    "rss": 42012672,
    "heapTotal": 17678336,
    "heapUsed": 16257912,
    "external": 1135594,
    "arrayBuffers": 144485
}
```

And the garbage collect log output like this:

```
[8:0x7f2c8b1873d0]    96157 ms: Scavenge 15.0 (16.1) -> 14.2 (16.1) MB, 0.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.874) task
[8:0x7f2c8b1873d0]   158138 ms: Scavenge 15.3 (16.4) -> 14.6 (16.6) MB, 0.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.874) task
[8:0x7f2c8b1873d0]   209744 ms: Scavenge 15.6 (16.9) -> 14.8 (16.9) MB, 0.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.874) task
[8:0x7f2c8b1873d0]   271586 ms: Scavenge 15.6 (16.9) -> 14.9 (16.9) MB, 1.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.874) task
[8:0x7f2c8b1873d0]   331585 ms: Scavenge 15.6 (16.9) -> 14.9 (16.9) MB, 0.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.874) task
[8:0x7f2c8b1873d0]   391721 ms: Scavenge 15.7 (16.9) -> 15.0 (16.9) MB, 0.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.874) task
[8:0x7f2c8b1873d0]   431839 ms: Scavenge 15.9 (16.9) -> 15.0 (17.1) MB, 0.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.874) allocation failure 
[8:0x7f2c8b1873d0]   431846 ms: Scavenge 15.9 (17.1) -> 15.2 (17.1) MB, 0.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.874) allocation failure 
[8:0x7f2c8b1873d0]   431874 ms: Scavenge 16.0 (17.1) -> 15.6 (17.4) MB, 0.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.874) allocation failure 
[8:0x7f2c8b1873d0]   431964 ms: Scavenge 16.2 (17.4) -> 15.6 (18.1) MB, 1.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.874) allocation failure 
[8:0x7f2c8b1873d0]   432170 ms: Scavenge 16.4 (18.1) -> 15.7 (18.1) MB, 1.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.874) allocation failure 
[8:0x7f2c8b1873d0]   432382 ms: Scavenge 16.7 (18.1) -> 15.8 (18.1) MB, 0.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.874) task 
[8:0x7f2c8b1873d0]   432478 ms: Scavenge 17.2 (18.4) -> 17.0 (18.6) MB, 1.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.874) allocation failure 
[8:0x7f2c8b1873d0]   432480 ms: Scavenge 17.3 (18.6) -> 17.2 (19.4) MB, 1.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.874) allocation failure 
[8:0x7f2c8b1873d0]   432572 ms: Scavenge 17.9 (19.4) -> 18.0 (19.4) MB, 88.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.874) allocation failure 
[8:0x7f2c8b1873d0]   432579 ms: Scavenge 18.2 (19.4) -> 18.0 (20.4) MB, 2.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.874) allocation failure
```

Why is the rss size so small? It should be greater than `max-old-space-size` + `max-semi-space-size`, maybe the application did not apply the full size of memory when start. But why the memory did not increase when reach the max heap size even through did not reach the max limit? It should reach to 128MB to trigger the garbage collection. this is the kubernetes pod resource define:

```
         resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 450Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 20m
              memory: 25Mi
```

what should I do to reduce the garbage collection frequency?